# Having different FA icon in the before and after states

Tags: icons

I'd like to have a different FA icon in the before and after state of the same button. In other words I display a button and it shows a FA "plus"icon. Then when I click the button a new screen comes up but the same button remains on the screen but now I want is to display a "close" FA icon. In my CSS I have this:

```
  .shape:before {
  content: "\f234";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }

  .shape:after {
  content: "\f00d";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

However what happens in that the button shows both button before and after states.  How do I only show the plus icon before the button is used and then the close icon once the button has to close the new screen?

Comment: I don’t think CSS is capable of logic in that way. You need to have an event take place, like your button press, and then have something respond to that event and then re-render your button with the new style. JS is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

`:before` and `:after` refer to positions in the DOM relative to the defined classes, not events.

You just need to:

- rename your classes without the pseudo elements (`:before` and `:after`), something like `.shape` and `.shape-opened` and remove everything from `.shape-opened` except the `content` property
- add some JavaScript to toggle these classes

Something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <style>
      .shape {
        content: "\f234";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        color:#fff;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 30px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
      }
      .shape-opened {
        content: "\f00d";
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      toggleClass = () => {
        // this assumes there's only one element with the class shape or that you only want the first one
        // You could also use the javascript `event` object to get the current
        var shape = document.getElementsByClassName('shape')[0];
        console.log(shape);
        if (shape.classList.contains('shape-opened')) {
          shape.classList.remove('shape-opened');
        } else {
          shape.classList.add('shape-opened');
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="shape" onClick="toggleClass()"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

(I threw the `console.log` in there so you could see the classes toggle in the console even if the content changes weren't working because of e.g. a dependency problem with FA.)